# Does Windows 7 have any stock widget software that replaces Gadgets?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I know that Gadgets was discontinued for security, and I know you can bring it back if you want.  But, is there a **stock**, **Microsoft created** alternative for pinning a program like a webpage to the desktop?  I have a status notification page I turned into a gadget a long time ago.  I'd like to do something with it to keep up with the latest technology as it relates to displaying it all the time on the desktop like Gadgets did.

Comment: No. You need to go 3rd party.

Comment: Windows Gagets functionality was retired due to the numerous design and security flaws

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping they made something I didn't know about to replace it.